# NuSoap Client call service with array

Tags: php, nusoap

I have web service wsdl look like this

[image: Web service]

If I do a call to a web service, I always get an error message

**Array to string conversion**

```
$client = new nusoap_client('https://www.myservice.php');
$ProsesSoap = $client->call('TransformerRequest',
array(
        'Gelar'=> $teststststst,
        'Nama_Plg' => $teststststst,
        'Jenis_Kelamin' => $teststststst,
        'Tempat_Lahir' => $teststststst,
        'Tgl_Lahir' => $teststststst,
        'Mobilephone1' => $teststststst,
        'Mobilephone2' => $teststststst,
        'Telepon_Rumah' => $teststststst,
        'Email' => $teststststst,
        'No_Identitas' => $teststststst,
        'Alamat_KTP' => $teststststst,
        '.....'
    )
);
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to avoid using nusoap and use a WSDL to php generator as it really eases the way to send the request. Indeed, using a WSDL to php generator gives you the availability to use an OOP approach to send the request by only using PHP objects that exactly match the methods and the parameters name. Moreover, it uses the native PHP SoapClient class.

You can use [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com) or the newest version at https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator.